# Enabling bracket operator syntax with Boost Property maps?

Tags: c++, boost-graph, boost-property-map

### My objective

I want to include property maps in a binary tree class, so I can access the graph vertices and write this syntax in the spirit of the BGL:

```
  using vertex_properties = std::string;
  using tree_type = binary_tree<vertex_properties, boost::no_property>;
  using vertex_descriptor = tree_type::vertex_descriptor;
  tree_type tree;
  vertex_descriptor a = add_vertex(tree, "a");
  vertex_descriptor b = add_vertex(tree, "b");
  assert(tree[a] == "a");
  tree[a] = tree[b];
  assert(tree[a] == "b");
```

### My problem

I got the the `add_vertex` function working but I struggle enabling the bracket operator syntax.

### What I tried

In the `tree_type` class I defined as a member an instance of the `VertexManager` class:

```
        template<typename Graph, typename VertexProperty>
        struct VertexManager
        {
            using vertex_descriptor = typename Graph::vertex_descriptor;
            using vertex_hashmap_type = std::map<vertex_descriptor, VertexProperty>;
            vertex_hashmap_type _vertex_property_hashmap;
            boost::associative_property_map< vertex_hashmap_type > _vertex_property_map { _vertex_property_hashmap };

            template<typename... Args>
            vertex_descriptor add_vertex_to_manager(Graph &g, Args&&... args)
            {
                vertex_descriptor key = add_vertex(g);
                VertexProperty value = { std::forward<Args>(args)...};
                put(_vertex_property_map, key, value);
                return key;
            }

            const VertexProperty& operator [](vertex_descriptor v) const
            {
                return get(_vertex_property_hashmap, v);
            }

            VertexProperty & operator [](vertex_descriptor v)
            {
                return get(_vertex_property_hashmap, v);
            }
        };
```

But it does not work, as the boost `get` function is defined with a const interface as follow:

```
  template <class T>
  inline const T& get(const T* pa, std::ptrdiff_t k) { return pa[k]; }
```

Is there a way to get a reference to an in-place element in the map?

Comment: Uff I just realized the `boost::associative_pproperty_map` has an `operator[ ]` that does exactly what I want. I thought the interface was only `get` and `put` :/ oopsie

Comment: consider posting your self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looking in the implementation of the `associative_property_map`: it implements the required `value_type& operator[const key_type& k]`. Although it's not very clear why this operator is marked as `const`:

```
  template <typename UniquePairAssociativeContainer>
  class associative_property_map
    : public boost::put_get_helper<
       typename UniquePairAssociativeContainer::value_type::second_type&,
       associative_property_map<UniquePairAssociativeContainer> >
  {
    typedef UniquePairAssociativeContainer C;
  public:
    typedef typename C::key_type key_type;
    typedef typename C::value_type::second_type value_type;
    typedef value_type& reference;
    typedef lvalue_property_map_tag category;
    associative_property_map() : m_c(0) { }
    associative_property_map(C& c) : m_c(&c) { }
    reference operator[](const key_type& k) const {
      return (*m_c)[k];
    }
  private:
    C* m_c;
  };
```